# react native splash screen get 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

I started a new react native application using :

```
react-native init myApplication
```

I started with splash screen so i used this library [react native spalsh screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

I linked the library to generate native code using this command :

```
react-native link react-native-splash-screen
```

And i added files using Xcode like this :

1. In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]
2. Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-splash-screen and add SplashScreen.xcodeproj
3. In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libSplashScreen.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries
4. To fix 'RNSplashScreen.h' file not found, you have to select your project → Build Settings → Search Paths → Header Search Paths to add: $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios

I build the app using Xcode in a real Iphone and i get this error in RNSplashScreen.h :

```
    /**
 * SplashScreen
 * 启动屏
 * from：http://www.devio.org
 * Author:CrazyCodeBoy
 * GitHub:https://github.com/crazycodeboy
 * Email:crazycodeboy@gmail.com
 */
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> // <------'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RNSplashScreen : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>
+ (void)showSplash:(NSString*)splashScreen inRootView:(UIView*)rootView;
+ (void)show;
+ (void)hide;
@end
```

'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

the Podfile :

```
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
    ...... # other libaries
    pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react- 
    native-splash-screen'
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ....  <------- other code
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

use

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I tried your way but i get this error : @interface RNSplashScreen : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>  <-----   No type or protocol named 'RCTBridgeModule'

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara could you share your ```AppDelegate```

Comment: I update my question and i added Podfile and AppDelegate

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara try replace ```#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>``` with ```#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"```

Comment: i triend and i get the this error : 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara check this - https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/215#issuecomment-532537228

Comment: thanks it works, i shouldn't link with react native link

Comment: I tried your suggested solution and  github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/…  too but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it work with you too

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

....
target 'ReactLib' do
  use_react_native!
  project 'ReactLib.xcodeproj'
end
```