# 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found in React Native 0.61.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am trying to create a custom native module for React 0.61.2.

I have created the Android version, however there seems to be some issue with iOS.

I'm trying to do the following command:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface PaypalSdk : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

And getting:

```
'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

It appears like there have been a lot of changes to how this works in early React Native .6 versions.

In another, earlier version of React, I added React.xcodeproj to my libraries and that worked, however that doesn't seem to be an option here, as React.xcodeproj was removed.

I am going through this issue, and have tested everything, but none of these things seems to work:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25838

I have also tried everything here as well, including delete React from my schemes and re-adding it:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24363

What might be causing this?

EDIT: part of my PaypalSdk.m file:

```
#import "PaypalSdk.h"
#import <PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile.h>
#import <PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalConfiguration.h>
#import <PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalOAuthScopes.h>
#import <PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalProfileSharingViewController.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation PaypalSdk

... various methods and properties here

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(generateCode:(NSString *)code callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
... more code here
    callback(@[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"code: %@", "test"]]);
}

@end
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166098/9432559

Comment: Now it says, "'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found"

Comment: try to install everything from pods again.

Comment: in /ios I typed pod deintegrate and then pod install and tried to build app again. Same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```swift
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

You typically would solve using this on **0.59x** versions:

```swift
#if __has_include("RCTBridgeModule.h")
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#else
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#endif
```

However, from RN **>= v0.60x**, we need to add .podspec to podfile for whichever 3rd party/custom library that complain unable to find React/{whatever.h}. So please, **don't** add the .a file into your Xcode's `Linked Framework and Libraries`.

To solve this, we can start doing:

1. Copy `podspec` from other 3rd party library (eg, RNDeviceInfo/etc..);
2. Create own `podspec` by replacing a few item (eg, **s.name**, **s.source**, **s.source_files**)

```
s.name   = "MyPayPalLib"
s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/my-super-repo/paypal-lib-repo.git", :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
```

.

Follow the next steps, taking care if you Library is hosted on npm/yarn/git (remote) or stored locally in your project's dir.

.

### A. If Remote Library:

1. Add this to track all your lib files:
   `s.source_files  = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"`
2. Add new lib to Podfile:
   `pod 'MyPayPalLib', :path => '../node_modules/MyPayPalLib'`
3. Do a `pod install`

### B. If Local Library:

1. Create this custom.podspec at the same custom library path, you would otherwise need to modify the above `s.source` path as your need.

```
s.source       = { :http => 'file:' + __dir__ + '/' }
s.source_files = "customLib/*.{h,m}"
```

2. Add new lib to Podfile:
   `pod 'MyPayPalLib', :path => '../localLibFolder/MyPayPalLib'`
3. Do a `pod install`

---

### SOLUTION:

After fix the error: `'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found in React Native 0.61.2`, the `NativeModules` object was empty.

So, after some research, we got the issue: the `s.source_files` prop had wrong value!

Always take careful to use the right `s.source_files` podspec prop.

The OP was using: `s.source_files = "react-native-paypal-sdk/*.{h,m}"`

However, this should be: `s.source_files = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"`

This is the recommended way for remote repository.

Comment: I no longer get the error above (missing bridge file), but having done this, my NativeModules are still empty

Comment: So nice to hear that you solved this issue! I think this new will need more details.

Comment: I included some details of my PaypalSdk.m file - I'm not sure what else you'd need - it should be sufficient to show up in NativeModules, should it not?

Comment: import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

var PaypalSdk = NativeModules.PaypalSdk;

PaypalSdk.generateCode('the_code_here');

Comment: No, this is all in a separate module (react-native-paypal-sdk). I have it working for Android but not for iOS. I import NativeModules from react-native and it always returns an empty object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212728/discussion-between-maycon-mesquita-and-cecil-rodriguez).