# 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found - React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a react-native-plugin project and I am faced with an issue in the iOS part.
When I tried to import the <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> the following error is appears:
'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

[image: 1]

I tried to add React by enter to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Clicking on the '+', but I couldn't find React target.

[image: 2]

Any ideas?

Comment: It is duplicate issue.
Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340802/6890414)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166098/9432559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, I needed to include "use_react_native!" in my Podfile.